# Data duplication using mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I wanted a guidance for one problem . Suppose i have one table `alphabets` (`alpha`, `id`).
In column `alpha` having value a-z and in column id all values are 1.

```
a  1
b  1
.  .
.  .
z  1
```

Now i want a database query to insert data like a-z but with id=2 .

Can anybody help me out .

Answer (score 6):

```
INSERT INTO alphabets (alpha, id)
SELECT alpha, 2
  FROM alphabets a
 WHERE id = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM alphabets
         WHERE alpha = a.alpha
           AND id = 2
       )
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause makes this query [idempotent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idempotent), i.e., it won't duplicate the id=2 rows if you run it twice.